# Pandas replace using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column that has null/missing values written as strings such as 'There is no classification', 'unkown: there is no accurate classification', and other variants. I would like to replace all of these values with `None`.

I have tried this but it isn't working:

```
df['Fourth level classification'] = df['Fourth level classification'].replace(
    to_replace=r'.*[Tt]here is no .*', value=None, regex=True
)
```

Furthermore, how can I make the entire `to_replace` string case insenensitive, so that it would also match with 'tHere is NO cLaSsification', etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['Fourth level classification'] = (df['Fourth level classification']
                                    .str
                                    .lower()
                                    .replace(r'(.*(there is no).*)', pd.isna, regex=True))
```

Comment: could you explain replace function, what its doing

Comment: Your regex also worked in the `pd.Series.replace` function I asked for: `df['Fourth level classification'] = df['Fourth level classification'].replace(
    to_replace=r'(.*([there is no]).*)', value=np.nan, regex=True
)`